# iOS - UIViewController, UITableView, UIScrollView and UISegmentedControl - oh my

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

So, simply put, I have the following setup:

UIViewController - this is the main, parentController

Within this main view, I have a UIScrollView at the very top, and a UITableView below it.
The UITableView is populated with core data via NSFetchedResultsController...

UIScrollView (The UIViewController is the delegate of this UIScrollView)
 |- Within this, I have 2 UIViews that I show: 1 contains a UISegmentedControl, the other just contains nothing but UILabels

When the segmentedControl's value changes (ie: A user clicks on it), I just want to reload the UITableView's list of rows by issuing a new fetchRequest (by just changing the predicate and refetching) to the NSFetchedResultsController.

However, that's *exactly* where I began having an issue.

Whenever I issue [tableView reloadData], the top-most UIScrollView (not the UITableView's ScrollView, but the extra one I added to the UIViewController) stop responding.

Before I ever issue [tableView reloadData], scrolling works just fine.  After I issue it, the scrollView stops responding, and scrolling stops completely.

I've tried all of the following:

- [self.topScrollView setScrollingEnabled:YES]
- self.topScrollView.delegate = self;
- [self.topScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640.0f, self.topScrollView.frame.size.height)];
- [self.topScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

I removed the UISegmentedControl completely.  What I did instead was put a button at the very top of the view, and just issued [tableView reloadData];.    It is when the tableView is reloaded, that the UIScrollView stops responding.

Is this a bug?   Am I completely missing something here?   The only thing I can even begin to think of is that the UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, and so that when the table reloads, it must be doing something to cause the topScrollView to either lose all sense of contentOffset/Size and/or its delegate or something...

Has anyone ever tried this?  Has anyone ever had this issue?

The only way I could solve this was by creating a ContainerView, splitting the header out into its own UIViewController, and then setting *that* UIViewController as the UIVScrolLView delegate and just handling the entire header there.

While this works - I'm kind of confused, and would really like to know if a better alternative exists...

Edit:  Here is a basic code example of what I was doing before I split it out the header into a ContainerView and just loaded it via embededSegue:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.topScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640.0f, self.topScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.topScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}

// .....

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"listItemCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Load the cell with what is in core data at this index path..
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark SegmentedControl Switch

- (IBAction)segmentedControlValueChanged {

    NSFetchRequest *aRequest = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest];
    NSPredicate *predicate;

    switch(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %@", @"incomplete"];
        break;

        case 1:
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %@", @"complete"];
        break;

        case 2:
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %@", @"deleted"];
        break;

        default:
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %@", @"none"];
        break;
    }

    [aRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

//    self.topScrollView.delegate = self;
//    [self.topScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640.0f, self.topScrollView.frame.size.height)];
//    [self.topScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
//    [self.topScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing any scroll view delegate methods? Because the table view's delegate will also be acting as a scroll view delegate (as you say, table view inherits from scroll view) so you might need some conditional logic in your delegate methods. Personally I'd do this with multiple view controllers and containment, but that's just me.

Comment: I did not implement any of the UIScrollView delegates in this instance, no.  But yeah, Containments with individual viewcontrollers is what i ended up using.  Just hated to do it, but, by doing so I did get some abstraction for free by doing so...   For me, it isn't so much that abstracting it out is what works - it's why it failed in the first place =)